# Rails 4:Simple-form checkbox for active and inactive post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, haml, simple-form

Have created a check box -Boolean function in Simple-form, wanted to know how the controller can hide the post when indicative from index.
When a user creates a post he has an option to hide the post from all the post list (index.html.haml). In the form i have created active Boolean input , So if active is true post is shown in the index and if active is false the post is hidden from index.

```html
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
 = f.input :post
 = f.input :active ,:input_html => { :checked => true }
 = f.submit

index.html.haml

- @posts.each do |post|
 %h2.post= link_to post.post, post



class PostsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_action :authenticate_user!,except:[:index,:show]

 def index
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  @post = Post.new

 end
```

Comment: Please explain more what you want to do.

Comment: @Marwen  When a user creates a post he has an option to hide the post from all the post list (index.html.haml). In the form i have created active Boolean input , So if active is true post is shown in the index and if active is false the post is hidden from index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you wanted to do, which is to hide the inactive posts on the `index` `action`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.where(active: true).order("created_at DESC")
  @post = Post.new
end
```

Comment: i tried to add a new page  called "views" and in controller added   def view
  @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")

Comment: getting an error Couldn't find Post with 'id'=view ...pointing to           def find_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end